# PHP MySQL small query timeout, have to set limit to 10

Tags: php, mysql, join, timeout

I am getting PHP timeout errors when calling mysql_query() for a relatively small query, so i have to set the limit to 10.

```
Fatal error: Maximum execution time of 120 seconds exceeded in C:\xampp\htdocs\data.php on line 19
```

I have removed the loop from the code, the code seems to hang at the mysql_query() function..

---

```
mysql_connect("192.168.50.250",$username,$password);
@mysql_select_db($database) or die( "Unable to select database");
$query = "SELECT T.Tag as 'Device', y.alarmdesc as 'AlarmType', a.Active, a.Cleared FROM gencore.gc_alarms a JOIN ist.Tree T ON(T.DeviceId = a.DeviceId)  JOIN GenCore.gc_alarmtypes y ON (a.alarmType = y.aid) LIMIT 10";

$result=mysql_query($query);

$num=mysql_numrows($result);

mysql_close();
?>
<table class="sortable resizable editable tableStyle2">
<tr class="headerStyle">
<th>Device</th>
<th>AlarmType</th>
</tr>
<?php
 $i=0;
while ($i < $num) 
{

    $f1=mysql_result($result,$i,"Device");
    $f2=mysql_result($result,$i,"AlarmType");

?>

<tr>
<td><?php echo $f1; ?></td>
<td><?php echo $f2; ?></td>

</tr>

<?php
    $i++;
} 
?>

</body>
</html>
```

The query executes very quick from anywhere else, and is only 340 rows, does anyone have
any pointers how to retrieve the small table from the DB?

Regards
Johan

Comment: There's no such function - `mysql_numrows`, only `mysql_num_rows`

Comment: Which line is number 19? Is it the `mysql_query()` one?

Comment: Yes, line 19 is the mysql_query.

Comment: I changed to mysql_num_rows, and no difference, this only wants to execute with the LIMIT statement, otherwise it deadlocks/times out

Answer (score 3):

You can extend the timeout with `mysql.connect_timeout` key in `php.ini`.

I also notice that `mysql_close()` should be positioned after using `mysql_result`, and you have a typo: `mysql_numrows` should be `mysql_num_rows`

Comment: Thanks, i did change that to 120 seconds which is more than enough to get the 340 rows...

Answer (score 1):

If you're having trouble with queries that don't complete in time, try running the `SHOW FULL PROCESSLIST;` command in a MySQL console. That will show you any locks that may be preventing your query from writing or reading data. Your problems sounds like there may be an active lock on the table you're trying to read from.

Comment: Hi, i doubt that, because i am able to execute the query via the mysql gui manager in less than 1 second..... Also able to query via C# .net instantly...

Comment: @Johan: Hi, I still suggest you check the processlist the next time it happens, because it will give you information what the query is doing, locks or not.

Comment: 203 | root | 192.168.60.252:56073 | ist  | Query   |   36 | Writing to net seems its hanging there...

Comment: | 204 | root | 192.168.60.252:54726 | ist  | Query   |   57 | Writing to net      <- I believe there is something wrong with the way PHP connects to the mysql server, where could the bottleneck be? This is all setup over LAN. Thanks

Comment: @Johan: Ok, if I'm not mistaken there may be some issues in the network connection between the database and the machine running PHP. How long does it run if you execute the query in the MySQL console on the PHP server? I'm guessing the GUI manager and C#.net are not on the PHP server?

Comment: ON PHP machine i get 391 rows in set (2 min 57.85 sec), and on MySQL server itself, 391 rows in set (0.00 sec), this is definately a nework issue, thank you very much for pointing me in the right direction.

Comment: @Johan: My pleasure! :) If you need to troubleshoot further, serverfault.com will probably be a good place to ask.