# Can't connect to MySQL server on 'IP' (4)

Tags: php, mysql, cron

Connection is already done but  Sometimes i got this error when running a **cron JOB script**

`Can't connect to MySQL server on 'myhost' (4)`

My script was running from 3 months . From yesterday I got the above response. My script is running correctly sometimes connection is successful but sometimes it is failed with above response.

Please tell me the correct reason with solution.

Comment: Is your mysql server on the same machine? If not, is your mysql server reachable from external ip address?

Comment: no, mysql server is not on same machine , DB server is reachable.  because connection is working but sometimes not connected. means if script run 10 times , then 1 time failure (may be). failure is 10% (approx.).

Comment: Perhaps you don't close the mysql_connection and you reach the limit of mysql connections at the same time? But i don't think this is the problem.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe it's a timeout on the connection.

Try extending it with this:
https://stackoverflow.com/a/5567251/1489237

Also, try this code to check the connection time and if a timeout is ocurring.

```
for($i=0;$i<100;$i++){
    $start = time();
    //mysql connection
    //check connection and outputs success/error message
    $end = time();
    echo "Elapsed time for connection $i is ". ($start-$end). " seconds.";
}
```

Comment: no, mysql server is not on same machine , DB server is reachable. because connection is working but sometimes not connected. means if script run 10 times , then 1 time failure (may be). failure is 10% (approx.).

Comment: that was my point, I noticed that it was not on the same machine and that's why I'm guessing a timeout in the connection. That's the only part that is possible to vary in the mysql connect. If it works 9/10 we're sure it's not credentials, firewall or missing drivers. So it's got to be a timeout issue.
That's why I suggested extending the timeout. You may also create a test script to do a for loop that connects and disconnects from this mysql server 100 times with and outputs the time taken. I will post some code